# Update a table with changes to a DataGridView

Tags: c#

Hi I'm new to C# and I have a form with `DataGridView` that gets its data from the access `Form` COMPONENTS and a button called `Accept_btn`. I'm trying to update the table with changes on the `DataGridView`. I have used the following code that I have got from a example in the Load event of the form.

```
connection.Open();
string query = "SELECT * FROM Cables";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = dt;

dtGrdVw.DataSource = bSource;
```

and in the button click event I have the code

```
da.update(dt);
```

My problem is that the button click event doesn't recognize the `DataAdapter` or the `DataTable`

Comment: Based on the context of `da` and `dt`, they are created in a method, therefore they do not exist to anything outside of that scope. If you declare the objects in the class instead of in the Initialise(probably) method, they will be accessible to everything in the class

Comment: The datagridview will not get updated until you do a dtGrdVw.DataSource = null.  The paint method for the control doesn't automatically get updated.  So the trick is to set the DGV Source to null, and then back to the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys got it work with you suggestions by putting the Datatable in the class and also making a new  Datatable in the button method as well as making the Datagridview source equal to null and then setting the source to the new DataTable.
Sorry for the late reply as I've no internet at home.